# Finding roos of the equation $\frac{(7-x)\sqrt{7-x} + (x-5)\sqrt{x-5}}{\sqrt{7-x} +\sqrt{x-5}}=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Find the roots of the equation,

$$\frac{(7-x)\sqrt{7-x} + (x-5)\sqrt{x-5}}{\sqrt{7-x} +\sqrt{x-5}}=2$$ 
 What I did till now $(7-x)^{3/2}+(x-5)^{3/2}/(7-x)^{1/2}+(x-5)^{1/2}$
Now what to do next?
Please help me out. I am stuck at this question since an hour

Comment: where is the equation?

Comment: I have edited the equation. Please see that :) @haqnatural

Comment: An equation usually has one of these $=$.

Comment: Apology @DonaldSplutterwit  I have edited it now

Comment: Did you mean
$$\frac{(7-x)\sqrt{7-x}+(x-5)\sqrt{x-5}}{\sqrt{7-x}+\sqrt{x-5}}=2\;\Large{?}$$

Comment: Please use at least brackets...

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos ... Thanks for that, I was doing what was literally in the question ... hopefully the OP will clarify ?

Comment: Note that for the square roots to be defined, $7 \geq x \geq 5$

Comment: Yes @ÁngelMarioGallegos Please, can anyone edit it. It's been a few weeks and I don't know how to write on stack exchange

Comment: To get multicharacter exponents, put them in braces.  When you write $(7-x)^3/2$ you want (7-x)^{3/2} to get $(7-x)^{3/2}$  Is the last $\sqrt{x-5}$ in the denominator?  Parentheses, please.

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos that is the right answer. How did you get that?

Comment: It must be $5\le x\le 7$.

Comment: @onlymaths for the square roots to be defined, the quantity inside must be greater than or equal to zero.. this is when $x$ is real of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $A^3+B^3=(A+B)(A^2-AB+B^2)$

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I am now able to solve this question. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Notice that $$A^3+B^3=(A+B)(A^2-AB+B^2)\qquad\text{for real numbers }A\text{ and }B$$
So $$\frac{A^3+B^3}{A+B}=A^2-AB+B^2$$

Comment: Got it @AngelMarioGallegos. You made it seem easy. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\sqrt{7-x},\;v=\sqrt{x-5}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&\frac{(7-x)\sqrt{7-x}+(x-5)\sqrt{x-5}}{\sqrt{7-x}+\sqrt{x-5}}=2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\frac{u^3+v^3}{u+v}=2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\frac{(u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2)}{u+v}=2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^2-uv+v^2=2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&uv=u^2+v^2-2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&uv=(7-x)+(x-5)-2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&uv=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u=0\;\;\text{or}\;\;v=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x=7\;\;\text{or}\;\;x=5\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
So the only *possible* solutions are $x=7$ or $x=5$.

If you substitute into the original equation, you can determine which of those work (if any).

In fact, they both work.

Comment: This is very easy @quasi. Thankyou so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Directly solving the equation,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(7-x)\sqrt{7-x}+(x-5)\sqrt{x-5}}{\sqrt{7-x}+\sqrt{x-5}} &= 2\\
(7-x)\sqrt{7-x}+(x-5)\sqrt{x-5} &= 2\left(\sqrt{7-x}+\sqrt{x-5}\right)\\
(5-x)\sqrt{7-x}+(x-7)\sqrt{x-5} &= 0\\
\sqrt{x-5}\sqrt{7-x}(\sqrt{x-5}+\sqrt{7-x}) &= 0
\end{align*}$$

The first two factors imply $x=5$ or $x=7$, and the third factor is always non-zero.

Comment: Thanks @peterwhy for taking out your time. You made it seem so so easy. Very greatful